# How do you cook up a cloning potion?

Tags: candy-box

> Cloning potion: There's a little bit of candies in everyone of us. This is actually a physical law of our universe. Now, candies are a very malleable material. These two facts led us to the realization of this cloning potion. The potion will copy your inner structure and make a clone of you almost entirely made of candies (there's a bit of water, too).
>
> Steps: Burn the water in your cauldron. Then, while it's still burning, add as many candies as you can. It's simple: the more candies you put, the more potions you'll get! (be sure to put a minimum quantity though)

These steps are incredibly vague. So how *do* you make a cloning potion? I have already dumped many candies in the cauldron to no avail. So how do you make one?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To brew a cloning potion:

1. Press `Boil`, without any candies or lollipops in the cauldron.
2. Wait until the following message appears: `Boiling... the water is burnt ! How is that even possible ?`
3. Place some candies into the cauldron.
4. Press `Stop` and put everything into bottles.

Candies will become cloning potions at a ratio of 1337 candies per cloning potion. (That is, using 1336 candies will get you nothing, and using 2000 will still make only one cloning potion, wasting 663 candies.)

Comment: Just curious, but does 1337 spells LEET in [Leet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leet). Coincidence?

Comment: @jeffreylin_ Most certainly not. :P

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to!
in the recipe potion it says to never put any candies in the berserk potion
if you put candies and lollipops in and then you get a cloning potion